# How do I add an image map link?

Tags: html, css, joomla, dictionary, hyperlink

I'm unsure if this is the correct approach, or even question, so I will elaborate.

Please visit this live page http://thedinnerparcel.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&Itemid=3

I am basically asking if it is possible to overlay a link somewhere in the header div? Specifically over the sticker background image on the right?

I didn't build the site, but I have just added the sticker to the right corner of the header div. (FYI it's a Joomla site so uses a PHP template file.).

I did this as a background image and used some padding and negative margin to make it overflow, then I realised the sticker needs to link to their order page.

Would an image map be the best way to make this into a link? Or is there a better method?

If an image map is the way has anyone got a code example.

I've tried the below code, which I edited from a tutorial on a similar subject, this doesn't work

```
<div id="header"  usemap="#Image-Maps_2201202140621298">
<map id="Image-Maps_2201202140621298" name="Image-Maps_2201202140621298">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,275,44" href="#" alt="Dinner Parcel" title="Dinner Parcel"/>
</map>
</div>
```

Comment: use different images, then link sticker to order page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paste the following code as is and it will work for you**

Append a `<a>` to the end of your header div:

```
<div id="header">
  <div...
  <div id="menu">...
  <a class="my-map" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

And then add the following styles:

```
#header{
   position:relative;
}

.my-map{
width: 190px;
height: 190px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 26px;
background: #EEE;
border-radius: 95px;
right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you. A few edits. I added a high z-index (999) to the .my-map class so it sits over everything, and changed the background value to transparent. This is much better than an image map!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how popular imagemaps are anymore :). You can position the element absolutely relative to the header with the following (for example). Codepen sketch: http://cdpn.io/klsEp

**HTML**

```
<div class='header'>
  <a class='sticker'>Click me</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Consider this simple example.

```
.header {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

.sticker {
  background: red url('..') no-repeat center;
  bottom: -20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.sticker:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, I cannot find the link to menu_bg6.png, but that is where you must put the `usemap=` tag, as in:

```
<img src="menu_bg6.png" alt="an image" usemap="#usethismap">
```

So, not on the DIV tag, but on the IMG tag.

Then you can create a corresponding `<map>` tag and it should work for you (although, don't forget to insert a URL for the click to action - currently yours is '#').

[Here is a simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twK2k/) with more ideas for positioning clickable areas over an image.

[Here is an article](http://www.neopets.com/~Kacizilla) that discusses how to create pseudo "image maps" for DIVs - without an IMG tag.